# Infinitely many planets on a line, with Newtonian gravity

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, differential-equations

(I previously asked essentially this [on physics.stackexchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/56843/infinitely-many-planets-on-a-line-with-newtonian-gravity), but was actually

hoping for answers with something closer to a proof than what I got there.)

Suppose we have a unit mass planet at each integer point in 1-d space. $\:$ As described in that answer, the sum of the forces acting on any particular planet is absolutely convergent. $\;\;$ Suppose we move planet_0

to point $\epsilon$, where $\: 0< \epsilon< \frac12 \:$. $\;\;$ For similar reasons, those sums will still be absolutely convergent.

Now we let Newtonian gravity apply. $\:$ What will happen?

If it's unclear what an answer might look like, you could consider the following more specific questions:

Will there be a positive amount of time before any collisions occur?

(As opposed to, for example, a collision at time $\frac1n$ for each positive integer $n$.)

"Obviously" (at least, I hope I'm right), planet_0 will collide with planet_1. $\:$ Will that be the first collision?

planet_0 will start out moving right, and all of the other planets will start out moving to the left.

Will there be a positive amount of time before any of them turn around?

How long will it be before there are any collisions? $\:\:$ (perhaps just an approximation for small $\:\epsilon\:$)

Comment: I read recently about a very similar problem that appeared in a 1949 letter from Ulam to von Neumann. (In that case the particles started at points of $\mathbb Z$ with each node being occupied with probability 1/2). He showed(?) that something analogous to the universe happens: nearby groups of particles come together; and then those "solar systems" form galaxies etc.

Comment: Of course if you really live in a 1D world, gravitational force presumably doesn't decay at all?

Comment: I think that as long as each planet is at most $\delta$ from its nearest integer, the total force on each planet is $O(\delta)$. This can be used to prove rigorously that there's a positive $\tau>0$ before any collision can occur. 

Comment: Yes, particles clump together, typically forming smaller systems first. This is studied extensively in cosmology, both analytically and numerically. Gravitational effects are easy to model, and affect dark matter. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8C_dnP2fvxk However, dissipative effects such as the inelastic contraction of gas clouds are important, too. 

Comment: Are the planets point masses, or some radius $r \lt \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: point masses $\:$

Comment: Excellent question! Perhaps  You should start as in thermodynamics with a large number $N$ of particles located at $-N,\dotsc,-1, \epsilon, 1,\dotsc, N$ and see what happens then. At least in this case the total energy is finite, which is not the case  when infinitely many  particles are present.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas is correct. The Poisson equation in one dimension in this case is $\phi''(x)=\delta(x)$ that has as a solution $\theta(x) x$. So, the potential between two bodies is not decaying in this case.

Comment: @Anthony Quas and Jon: I think this is not what he means. He does not "live in 1D world" but in 3-space. Just the planets happen to be on the line. The gravity law must be inverse squares. Otherwise the questions make no sense.